# Getting java.net.ConnectException while performing Ant build on my application

Tags: java, connection-timeout

I am performing Ant build on my application and every time I am getting the java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
I tried the answers for the similar questions but no success. :(
I am attaching the stack-trace of the Ant Build.

```html
[assemble-jar] java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.xml.XMLFileEntityResolver.resolveLocalEntity(XMLFileEntityResolver.java:372)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.xml.XMLFileEntityResolver.resolveEntity(XMLFileEntityResolver.java:286)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.dtds.j2ee.J2EEEntityResolver.resolveEntity(J2EEEntityResolver.java:470)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.dtds.j2ee.J2EEEntityResolver.resolveEntity(J2EEEntityResolver.java:465)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.appassembly.util.MetaInfGeneratorImpl.createUnmarshallerHandler(MetaInfGeneratorImpl.java:568)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.appassembly.util.MetaInfGeneratorImpl.loadApplicationXm5FromStream(MetaInfGeneratorImpl.java:480)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.appassembly.EarInfoFactory.getJ2EEModulesForEar(EarInfoFactory.java:261)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.appassembly.EarInfoFactory.processEARModules(EarInfoFactory.java:235)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.appassembly.EarInfoFactory.createEarInfo(EarInfoFactory.java:143)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.appassembly.ApplicationAssembler.getEarInfoFromDynModules(ApplicationAssembler.java:273)
[assemble-jar]  at atg.appassembly.ant.CreateUnpackedEarTask.execute(CreateUnpackedEarTask.java:476)
[assemble-jar]  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[assemble-jar]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Kindly help me out from this issue.

Regards

Comment: where it is trying to connect  to ? from test ? or some task ? check network configuration based on that

Comment: Any possible way you can increase timeout and see what happens?

Comment: Are you executing a 'xmlvalidate' task within your Ant build? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @lokesh: Can you please explain, which timeout you are talking about?

Comment: @jigar: I am not sure where it is connecting to. The build script is already created by other people and I am trying configure accordingly in the local system. Can you please explain your question a bit?

Comment: @CristianMeneses :yes, we are behind the proxy and executing the 'xmlvalidate' task.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: You can change timeout in tomcat, if your problem still exists then you need to ask your networking person to fix the firewall which is blocking you to access this resource.

Answer (score 1):

got same issue , fixed after I commented the line

`<setproxy proxyhost="<ip>" proxyport="<port>"/>`

Comment: can you please mention where you removed this line.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I found this line when I navigated through the whole ant script trying to figure out where it is trying to connect to some external ip, so you may search for a similar line or try to figure out anything else trying to connect to external ip (which is not reachable by your machine)